# Sort a List<Object> based on field name by reflection

Tags: java, sorting

I have a model like that :

```
public class Contact {

    private int id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String address;

    private String city;

    private String state;

    private String zipCode;

    private String mobilePhone;

    private String email;

    private String dayOfBirth;

    private int age;

    public String toLine() {
        return String.format("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", id, firstName, lastName, dayOfBirth, address, city, state, zipCode, mobilePhone, email);
    }
}
```

I write a sort function to sort List by field name by using reflection but `field.get(contact1)` have no method compareTo. Any way to achieve it ? BTW, any way to make toLine function shorter ? it seem too long.

```
    public void sortByFieldName(String fieldName, List<Contact> validContacts) throws NoSuchFieldException {

        Field field = Contact.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);

        validContacts.stream().sorted((contact1, contact2) -> field.get(contact1).compareTo(field.get(contact2)));
}
```

I do not want to use this because it seem to be not flexible:

```
if (fieldName.equals("zipCode")) {
            validContacts.sort(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getZipCode));
        }
```

I removed the getters and setters because it's too long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any reflection at all. You can use `Comparator#comparing` for that:

```
List<Contact> sortedContacts = validContacts.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getZipCode))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course this assumes that your class has getter methods, which it didn't in your question. If this is the case and the fields are accessible, you can also use `c -> c.zipCode` instead of `Contact::getZipCode`. If neither is the case and the class really looks like what you've shown, the fields would be useless as no one would have access to them (unless it's a static class within another class).

---

If you absolutely do need to do this using reflection – *which I really think you don't* –, then you can do it like this. But I'd say this is much more specific and not reusable whatsoever. Using the stream API as shown above would be better:

```
public static List<Contact> sortByFieldName(List<Contact> list, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    Field field = Contact.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    if (!String.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Field is not a string!");
    }

    field.setAccessible(true);
    return list.stream()
        .sorted((first, second) -> {
            try {
                String a = (String) field.get(first);
                String b = (String) field.get(second);
                return a.compareTo(b);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error", e);
            }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I know this but if use it, we have to use if else like I said, I want to make a general sort function that I can pass the field name and sort the list by that field without if else. My model have getters and setters but I removed because it's too long

Comment: This works without if / else. At some point you need to pass the name of the field, right? So instead of passing a string there, just pass the `Contact::getZipCode` handle.

Comment: I am sorry I have not understood. What if I want to sort by id ? It will be like this right ?
`List<Contact> sortedContacts = validContacts.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getId))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());`

so my method will be:

`if (fieldName.equals("id")){
    // Contact::getId
} else if (fieldName.equals("zipCode")){
    // Contact::getZipCode
}`

Comment: In my answer you no longer need your own method. It already does the sorting based on the field, that's what `Comparator#comparing` does: it extracts a field from the object to compare on. Your `sortByFieldName` is not needed at all.

Comment: @ThachHuynh I've also added a reflection version if you absolutely do want to go down that route. But as I said, you don't need your custom method at all, just use `Comparator.comparing(Contact::getXyz)` as described in my answer. Please also accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @IngoBürk Currently, the Contact list is sorting by the property zip code. Suppose what if we want to change the sorting property dynamically. How can we do this? I mean how to change the sorting property in the below code, List<Contact> sortedContacts = validContacts.stream() .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getZipCode)) .collect(Collectors.toList()); using the sorting input from the user.